# Is it possible to read/access the bar-code scanner values using PHP & MySQL?

Tags: php, barcode, barcode-scanner

I am trying to enable a PHP website to recognize barcode input.

I will load a web page in a browser, the focus (cursor) is set to recieve input into the text box.

I will be having a barcode reader/scanner plugged into the PC and will scan the barcodes one-by-one using the scanner. Would the information from the barcode can be put into the text box of the web page ?

The important question is that how can I read the output from the scanner using PHP ?

Please advise.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Had a similar problem. Barcode scanners work like keyboards, they just enter a string. The scanners can usually be configured so that they add a prefix or a postfix to the characters read from the barcode, often on a per barcode-type basis (can have different config for Code 39 than for Code 128 e.g.)

But, a problem that we had in our last project was, that the guys that developed the cashier system also configured the barcode scanner and they put a CTRL-B as a prefix in front of every barcode. In Firefox, this opens up the Bookmarks and so you´re trapped.

What I mean is, connecting the scanner is easy, but you have to care for the configuration of the scanner if there are control character that might be captured by the browser or some other software. On the other hand, this can be very useful cause you can enter a linefeed after each barcode or something else that helps you separate them.

Another important aspect in our case was the timing. The barcode scanners enter the character quite fast, but - at least the one we had - entered it one by one. So when we tested our functionality, there was a huge difference between the string pasted from the clipboard or the string scanned from the barcode. This was relevant for Ajax-Calls we did (where in our case, a ZK-based website had lots of trouble with that).

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 4):

This is not a programming question per se. Bar code scanners work just like a keyboard, they input the digits scanned.

The easiest way is to just create a form with a textbox and then post it and handle it with your PHP code

Comment: Thanks to everyone. It seems to be like that I can use a keyword wedge(http://www.wisegeek.com/what-is-a-keyboard-wedge.htm). So I'm hoping that the workload is greatly reduced.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot read the barcode using PHP, because it's a serverside language, but the input would be client-side.

What you could do, is write a little program which gets the barcode and puts it into your browser textbox or sends it via GET / POST to your php script.

Answer (score 2):

As already stated, bar code scanners usually only send a sequence of characters to the computer, much like a keyboard.

If you want to make an efficient scanner, I would recommend using JavaScript and making an

```
<input type="text">
```

that sends the bar code by AJAX on a validated change or keyup-event.

Answer (score 1):

Barcode scanners act just like a keyboard in the sense that they will input whatever barcode text into whatever focused field you have. I would set up a form with a text box for input. Submit said form to a php page to process the input. Access the variable like so

```
$_GET['variable'] or $_POST['variable']
```

depending on your form post method

Answer (score 1):

Most barcode scanners emulate a keyboard.

So as long as the input field has focus when the button is pressed on the scanner, a string with numbers will be written to the field and you can save those.