# Scan Barcode - Save Code in SQL Database

Tags: php, mysql, barcode, barcode-scanner

I am facing a problem and I have no idea how to solve this issue. I am using a MetroLogic MS9500 Voyager Barcode Scanner for one of my projects. My goal is that everytime I scan a barcode, the scanned number is to be saved inside a MySQL database together with date & current time.

I have absolutely no idea how this gonna work! Do I have to save those information local on my machine and upload a file to my database or how can I do that?

Currently I can open my editor and scan for example the barcode with the number "0000000000772" than inside the editor file the number will be automatically written. That is good but I have no idea how to get those number in a MySQL database.

Is there somewhere who can help me or let me know what I can/should do?

Comment: Barcode scanners just send text data. Scan the text into a form field and post it as a normal form.

Comment: That is not the solution that I need so I do not understand why you down-vote my question! I am going to scan about 500 barcodes per day! I cannot enter all those scans manually per day in a form! I need that those barcodes are saved somewhere and once a day uploaded to my MySQL database or something like this! I need this process to work automatically.

Comment: @ChristophC. votes are anonymous, so it could be anyone (was not me anyway). Plus, now you mention something else in your comment which should have been part of your question. As it stands, that would be pretty broad.

Comment: lol. THIS IS the solution you need.

Comment: if you want it done automatically, then you need to setup a cron job.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7227535/is-it-possible-to-read-access-the-bar-code-scanner-values-using-php-mysql Dont know how to close as duplicate.

Comment: @Kisaragi for future reference, just type in, and exactly as: possible duplicate of (link). The system/users should pick up on it, or you can flag the question as a duplicate if you can't vote to close yet.

Comment: @Kisaragi thanks for your link! That helped me! I searched before but I did not find the entry.

Comment: http://www.idautomation.com/hosted-saas-barcode-generator/streaming-integration/mysql-php.html should be of help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some years ago I had a similiar problem,the first thing that I understood was a Barcode scanner is like a keyword entri. you can write a form with html and then process with php, for other hand yo can will connect a excel to database via odbc and put a form or a macro vbs that take the value´s cell and insert into table on database.